# Android NFS Client

Tags: java, android, nfs, nfsclient

I have found a good library to implement an Android NFS Client ['nfs-client-java'](https://github.com/EMCECS/nfs-client-java), I'm creating an Nfs3 Client and I can access files and create new files... on the server. But the problem is that I can't mount the whole shared directory from the server. On Linux NFS Client, I can specify the mount point with

```
mount -t nfs -o nolock,rw,vers=3 192.168.1.10:/media/user/ /mnt/media_rw/remote
```

where `/mnt/media_rw/remote` is where the shared directory will be mounted.

My question is: How can I achieve the same result on Android App ?

Comment: are you sure this question isn't off-topic here ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that isn't

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried and the exception that the code had?

Comment: @Javier: No, I don't have tried

Answer (score 0):

In Android app development, there's no mounting at the Linux vfs layer. So you wouldn't be able to achieve exactly the same result.

There closest thing I'm aware of is the documents provider system https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider. From the documentation:

> A document provider offers read and write access to durable files, such as files stored on a local disk, or files in a cloud storage service.

You'd implement methods such as `openFile` in your NFS documents provider by, for example, downloading a copy through the library you found, opening it, and forwarding a parcelable file descriptor in the return value.